# JPA Hibernate ManyToMany Error creating relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

JPA with Hibernate on Wildfly 9.

I have 2 entities that are `ManyToMany`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET_GROUPS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "AssetGroup.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AssetGroup a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "AssetGroup.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM AssetGroup a WHERE a.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "AssetGroup.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM AssetGroup a WHERE a.name = :name") })
public class AssetGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "asset_groups_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "asset_groups_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "asset_groups_id_seq_gen")
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;

     @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinTable(
          name="ASSETS_ASSET_GROUPS",
          joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ASSET_GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
          inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ASSET_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private List<Asset> assets;
    ...
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSETS")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Asset.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Asset a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Asset.findById", query = "SELECT a FROM Asset a WHERE a.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Asset.findByName", query = "SELECT a FROM Asset a WHERE a.name = :name")
    })
public class Asset implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "assets_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "assets_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "assets_id_seq_gen")
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="assets")
    List<AssetGroup> assetGroups;

    public Asset() {
    }
    ...
```

I can add these things no problem via a REST service, but this code gives me an error:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Transactional
public void create(Asset entity) {
    L.info("Creating {}", entity);
    AssetGroup g = groupService.findAll().get(0);
    L.info("Adding to asset group {}", g);
    super.create(entity);
    L.info("Created Asset {}", entity.getId());
    g.addAsset(entity); // <---- Works if this is commented out but does not create relationship!
    L.info("Created");
}
```

Here is the output from the above function:

> 11:05:29,667 INFO  [auth.entities.service.AssetGroupsFacadeREST]
>    (default task-2) Creating entities.AssetGroup@bbad39d
>
> 11:05:29,672 INFO  [auth.entities.service.AssetGroupsFacadeREST] (default task-2) Created
>
> 11:05:29,703 INFO  [auth.entities.service.AssetsFacadeREST]
>   (default task-3) Creating entities.Asset@1be5f67a
>
> 11:05:29,728 INFO [auth.entities.service.AssetsFacadeREST] default task-3) Adding to asset group entities.AssetGroup@323e7d95
>
> 11:05:29,728 INFO [auth.entities.service.AssetsFacadeREST] (default task-3) Created Asset 1
>
> 11:05:29,728 INFO  [auth.entities.service.AssetsFacadeREST] (default task-3) Created
>
> 11:05:29,730 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>
> 11:05:29,730 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3)
>   ERROR: insert or update on table "assets_asset_groups" violates foreign key constraint "fk_6bl48uhb94hsmq6knndfiq3y"   Detail: Key (asset_id)=(1) is not present in table "assets".

It's pretty obvious that the DB is failing due to the Asset id 1 being persisted, so how do I fix this?  I have tried doing a commit() on the entity manager, but it does not work.  I have tried annotating the `super.create(entity)` method with a `@Transactional` annotation requiring a new transaction, and nothing works.

Note that if I comment out the commented line, the entity is saved but the relationship is not created in the linking table.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

In my service classes, I have:

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "net.mikeski_auth_war_0.1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

So, the `getEntityManager()` function did `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()`, which resulted in the service providing the groups having a different `EntityManager` than the service providing the assets.  This meant that the insert into asses was in a separate transactional context from the insert into the relation table, and it was not working.

If I use the same entity manager for all method calls, it works.